# Can I copy my Master League file to another computer?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2013

I play a Master League from PES 2013 on my laptop and have just re-installed Windows on my PC.

Is there any way to copy my Master League file from my laptop to my PC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

By default, Pro Evolution Soccer 2013 places save data (amongst other things) in the user's Documents directory.

The full path will be something similar to below:
`C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents\KONAMI\Pro Evolution Soccer 2013`

**Nicholas** would be replaced with your username.

It is possible to copy the **KONAMI** folder, or individual files from the source computer to the same/similar directory on the target computer. Especially in the case of only copying individual files, remember to maintain the same folder structure (`\KONAMI\Pro Evolution Soccer 2013`).

The save and option files copied to the target computer will be present when you next start the game.